# How to write several scope names in karate feature?

Tags: karate

Karate version: 0.6.0 Java version: 1.8
I've put scope names (needed for token generation) in a json file.

```
{"scopeFoo": "foo",
  "scopeBar": "bar",
  "scopeRead": "read",
  "scopeWrite": write}
```

In karate feature I would like to have

```
* def sc = read(scopes.json)    
* form field scope = "foo bar read write"
```

When I do:

```
* def sc = read(scopes.json) 
* form field scope = sc.scopeFoo + sc.scopeBar + sc.scopeRead + sc.scopeWrite
```

It doesn't work. Even without spaces:

```
* form field scope = sc.scopeFoo+sc.scopeBar+sc.scopeRead+sc.scopeWrite
```

What is wrong? Thanks
I can access scopes.json file in my feature, because with one scope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to concatenate everything into one single string, try wrapping in parentheses. This is explained more in the documentation on [Karate expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions):

```
form field scope = (sc.scopeFoo + sc.scopeBar + sc.scopeRead + sc.scopeWrite)
```